# URL Rewriting with .htaccess gets 403

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have what I think is a very simple URL rewrite but it doesn't work. Here's the .htaccess file:

```
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.html
ErrorDocument 400 /errors/400.html
ErrorDocument 401 /errors/401.html
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.html
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500.html


RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule   ^help/?$   help/help.html  [NC]
```

but what happens when I try to resolve mysite.com/help is I get 403. (Apache server)

Below these lines are a long series:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^BlackWidow [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Bot\ mailto:craftbot@yahoo.com [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ChinaClaw [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Custo [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^DISCo [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Download\ Demon [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^eCatch [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EirGrabber [OR]
```

both .htaccess files are identical.

Comment: Do you have .htaccess in `/help/` directory also?

Comment: yes. I suspect it's something rather trivial, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Did you check presence of `/help/.htaccess` file?

Comment: Ok post the content from that file as well.

Comment: I edited the original post to include more of the content.

Comment: Ok for testing rename `/help/.htaccess` and then see how it behaves.

Comment: That was the solution.

Comment: But don't you need `/help/.htaccess` for its rules?

Comment: I have .htaccess off the root. Now it works perfectly (so far)

Comment: Was this answer of use: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/56938/29140